# Initializing fully connected ssh network

Tags: ssh, networking

I have five Linux machines with a service account on each under the same name. They all have a subnet connection to each other (`192.168.1.{1,2,3,4,5}`).

I have a script that parses `/etc/hosts` and adds the proper ip's to the proper host names. Each machine needs to be able to initiate password-less `ssh` to every other machine (15 non-trivial routes). This all works fine, but it is a lot of work managing if a new machine is added or a machine is removed. My question is this:

Given a fully connected network of machines, how do I manage connections on each machine at the same time? e.g. Make every machine talk to every other without manually adding keys and editing hosts

Comment: [Certificates](https://blog.habets.se/2011/07/OpenSSH-certificates). Too long story for a good answer ...

Comment: That looks like 20 (5x4) routes to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short:

## Host keys

1. Create CA key for host keys:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -f host_ca
   ```
2. Sign all host keys and copy them to the server:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -s host_ca -I host_foo -h -n foo.bar.com -V +52w /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
   ```
3. Configure server (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) to advertise certificates (in addidtion to host keys):

   ```
   HostCertificate /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key-cert.pub
   ```
4. Configure clients (`/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`) (also your server if you search for mutual communication):

   ```
   @cert-authority *.bar.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3[...]== Comment
   ```

## Authentication keys:

1. Create CA key for users:

   ```
    ssh-keygen -f user_ca
   ```
2. Configure server to accept keys signed by this CA (again in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config'):

   ```
   TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/user_ca.pub
   ```
3. Sign the authentication key:

   ```
    ssh-keygen -s user_ca -I user_thomas -n thomas,thomas2 -V +52w /path/to/id_rsa.pub
   ```

More notes are available on [habets.se](https://blog.habets.se/2011/07/OpenSSH-certificates) or in manual page for [`sshd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd). It should answer all your questions, but if not, feel free to ask further.

Comment: This works with a centralized server, but how about a distributed network where they are all neither server nor client but both?

Comment: It works in your configuration too, but you need to sign for every machine both host and authentication keys.